# Backup-SPFarm : You need to have Machine administrator priviliges to run this cmdlet

Tags: administration, sharepoint-on-prem, backup, farm

I am working on a sharepoint on-premises farm 2016, and i created a scheduler task to do a backup for the whole farm + each site collection separately.

here is the action inside the task scheduler:-

[image]

here is the `backup.bat` file:-

```
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'%~dp0\backup.ps1'"
```

and the `backup.ps1`, is as follow:-

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \\***\Back -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force
Backup-spsite -identity http://***/  -path c:\Back\main.bak –force
Backup-spsite -identity http://***/sites/Info   -path c:\Back\info.bak –force
Backup-spsite -identity http://***/offices/  -path c:\Back\offices.bak –force
```

now i have noted that the task will only create 3 `.bak` files representing the site collection backups, but the first command for backuping the farm will not generate any files/folder, and when i tried to run this command manually i got this error:-

```
PS C:\batchfiles> C:\batchfiles\backup.ps1
Backup-SPFarm : You need to have Machine administrator priviliges to run this cmdlet.
```

although i am defining to run the scheduler task with highest privileges:-
[image]

so can anyone advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to the beginning of your script:

It will elevate if you are not exectuing as admin:

```
# The following section was taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script.aspx
# This section is used to ensure we are running the script "As Administrator" so we don't get access denied errors when we run 
# commands that require administrator permissions.
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
   # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
   $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
   $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
   clear-host
}
else
{
    # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator
    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
    $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    exit
}
##########################################################################################################################################
```